# Any idea on how this shader may have been made?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

Any idea on how this shader may have been made? I have already tried asking the creator but it look like they don't want to respond

I was mainly interested in the grainy effect they have on the borders, like they have been drawn with pastels and they're not smooth.

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I do have one of the many ways to do the cel shading alone.

The cel shading can be done with plugging a shader node into a **Shader to RGB** node, then plug the color output into a **ColorRamp** node.

Note : currently the **Shader to RGB** only works in EEVEE and not cycles.

But about the pastel effect, I'm simply going to guess it was done in **Compositing** or maybe done with the program **EBSynth**.

Comment: Also may I ask where you got this image from? IMO it's rude to just repost someone's art or animation without credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using toon shading for the characters (and objects, I presume), a simple *Lens Distortion* node in the compositor should go pretty far (note you may not need as strong a Dispersion as I used in the example, I just wanted to make sure it showed up in the screenshot so I made it extra strong. Also, I only increased the distortion to 1 to "zoom in" the image in the preview - you should be fine leaving it at 0):

[image: Distort]

If you want to go one further, try adding a *Glare* node set to *Fog Glow*:

[image: Glare]

These settings might be more correct for your image, though you may need to tweak the glare threshold to fit your lighting (just make sure to enable projector on the Lens Distortion, as it stops the whole scene from warping spherically).

[image: BetterGlare]